# Program to draw 3D charts graphics?

Tags: software-recommendation, 3d, image-editor

I want to create something like the image:

[image]

Can anyone suggest a simple application to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Try Octave.

> Octave is a high-level language, primarily intended for numerical
>   computations. It provides a convenient command-line interface for
>   solving linear and nonlinear problems numerically.<sup>1</sup>

To install, you can download it from [source](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/octave/), or by clicking [**Octave** [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/octave/)

Gnuplot.

> Gnuplot is a portable command-line driven graphing utility for Linux,
>   OS/2, MS Windows, OSX, VMS, and many other platforms.  It was
>   originally created to allow scientists and students to visualize
>   mathematical functions and data interactively, but has grown to
>   support many non-interactive uses such as web scripting. It is also
>   used as a plotting engine by third-party applications like Octave.
>   Gnuplot has been supported and under active development since 1986.<sup>2</sup>

To download and install click [Gnuplot development](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuplot/files/)

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[Ubuntu Apps](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/octave/)</sup>

<sup><sup>**2**</sup>Source:[Gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/)</sup>

Comment: Why unaccept after over a year?